# In Lua, is there a function that will tell me what current version I'm running?

Tags: lua, version

Subject says it all. I would like to know if my host interpreter is running Lua 5.2 or 5.1

Comment: Ah ... there is a global variable called _VERSION:

Comment: World of Warcraft (8.2 Battle for Azeroth): `5.1`

Comment: World of Warcraft Classic Era: `/dump _VERSION` → "Lua 5.1"

Answer (score 34):

There is global variable _VERSION (a string):

```
print(_VERSION)

-- Output
Lua 5.2
```

---

**UPD :**
Other methods to distinguish between Lua versions:

```
if _ENV then 
  -- Lua 5.2
else
  -- Lua 5.1
end
```

---

**UPD2 :**

```
--[=[
local version = 'Lua 5.0'
--[[]=]
local n = '8'; repeat n = n*n until n == n*n
local t = {'Lua 5.1', nil,
  [-1/0] = 'Lua 5.2',
  [1/0]  = 'Lua 5.3',
  [2]    = 'LuaJIT'}
local version = t[2] or t[#'\z'] or t[n/'-0'] or 'Lua 5.4'
--]]
print(version)
```

Comment: Be careful - `_ENV` can be intentionally set to `nil`.

Comment: @finnw - Even `math.pi` can be intentionally set to `3`  :-)

Comment: I think you meant `Lua 5.2 or greater`, as `Lua 5.3` also has the `_ENV` global variable.

Comment: @JeromeJ - Yes, of course.  Lua 5.3 didn't exist in 2013.

Comment: [More](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2016-05/msg00297.html) about detecting Lua version

Comment: I think `9^33 == 27^22` is true even on LuaJit (At least on LuaJit 2.0.4).

Comment: @Royi - The result depends on whether 64-bit double (LuaJIT) or 80-bit extended (vanilla Lua) is used for calculation.

Comment: I just tried it on the latest Zero Brane Studio which uses LuaJit 2.0.4. It yields: `9^33 == 27^22
true
print(jit.version)
LuaJIT 2.0.4`. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335340.

Comment: One more crazy check: `if 0x123456789 == 0x987654321 then --Lua 5.1`

Comment: [Now with Lua 5.4 support](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2020-07/msg00323.html)

Answer (score 3):

`_VERSION` holds the interpreter version. Check the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-_VERSION) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

If you also need the third digit in Lua version (not available in `_VERSION`) you need to parse the output of `lua -v` command on the command line.

For platforms that support io.popen this script will do the trick, but only if the script is run by the standalone interpreter (not in interactive mode).IOW the `arg` global table must be defined:

```
local i_min = 0
while arg[ i_min ] do i_min = i_min - 1 end
local lua_exe = arg[ i_min + 1 ]

local command = lua_exe .. [[ -v 2>&1]] -- Windows-specific
local fh = assert( io.popen( command ) )
local version = fh:read '*a'
fh:close()

-- use version in the code below

print( version )
print( version:match '(%d%.%d%.%d)' )
```

Note that `lua -v` writes on `stderr` on Windows (for Linux I don't know), so the `command` for io.popen (which only captures `stdout`) must redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and the syntax is platform-specific.

Comment: The third digit identifies different bug-fix releases with no change of functionality. It seems pointless to test those.

Comment: @lhf in general I fully agree, but for special needs it is a trick useful to know. E.g. say you want to discover if your script is run by an interpreter that has a particular patch applied or it is an older one (maybe you must run the script on a system not under your control, so you don't know whether a workaround in the code must be used or not). But I admit it is a bit on the nitpicker's side :-)

Comment: On Linux '`lua -v`' writes to `stdout` with Lua 5.2 but to `stderr` with Lua 5.1, but since the syntax for the redirection is the same in the (Bourne) shell, you can use the same command string on Linux and Windows (and almost certainly on OS X too).